# Fetching the two values from second inner array

Tags: javascript, arrays

hey guys am a javascript developer..I have a multidimensional array..

My array structure looks like

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]]
```

What i want to display is `4544 and 34` from a single code(not by slicing or replacing)

My code is

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]]
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
console.log(m[i][j]);
}
}
```

This code outputs me `1,23,4544 and 34`.

The output i needed is `4544 and 34`..

Thanks..

Comment: `m[1][0]` and `m[1][1]` ?

Comment: Why don't you do `m[1][0]` and `m[1][1]`?

Comment: i know that way ..but isnt there any option by looping ??'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the first for loop you have, but the second can work, even though it is not necessary. With the loop you can do

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]];
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    console.log(m[1][i]);
}
```

This will just print the first two elements from the second array inside the `m` array. You can also do this easily without a loop like this

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]];
console.log(m[1][0]);
console.log(m[1][1]);
```

They are both relatively short and they both produce the result

```
4544
34
```

---

What is wrong with the current code you have

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]]
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        console.log(m[i][j]);
    }
}
```

With your first loop, you are actually iterating through the first two nested arrays that you have. Then, you are looping through the first two items in each of those. This is why you get the result of

```
1
23
4544
34
```

Since you only need items in the second nested array, there is no reason to have a second loop. Of course, you could do

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]]
for(i=1;i<2;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
        console.log(m[i][j]);
    }
}
```

but that would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the first index fixed and only loop on the second index

```
var j, i=1
for (j=0;j<2;++j) {
    console.log(m[i][j])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var m = [[1,23,4],[4544,34,54],[6,7,68]]

for(j=0;j<2;j++) {
console.log(m[1][j]);
}
```